# Cascade(Waterfalls) particles animation - openframeworks, alternatives

Tags: opengl, animation, particles

Has anyone tried to create a waterfall particles animation using openframeworks? Is it possible? Is it good?

If not, can you recommend any other frameworks for easier creation of cascade animation?

Thanks a LOT!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Lewis' answer, the ParticleDesigner is easy to use and you can also design a bit using a [flash port of the editor](http://onebyonedesign.com/flash/particleeditor/).

[image: Partidle Editor preview]

The presets are xml files anyway. The cool thing is there is also an [OpenFrameworks addon](https://github.com/sroske/ofxParticleEmitter) for this. Also, if you're not happy with this you can try other [ofxAddons](http://ofxaddons.com/) or learn how to make a [GLSL shader based particle waterfall](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=waterfall%20glsl&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with iOS check out this, they have loads of waterfall emitters.

http://particledesigner.71squared.com/